# Eslint: Parsing error: Unexpected token ... (seperator ES)

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, eslint

I want to add seperators in my code and when I use it like `app.use(session({...config.session}));` I have an error from ESLINT and actually my codes run without any bug or system error...
this is my eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "ecmaFeatures": {
        "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
        "forOf": true,
    },
    "rules": {
        'no-console': 'off',
        "indent": [
            "error",
            2
        ],
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "unix"
        ],
        "quotes": ["error", "single", {
            avoidEscape: true,
            allowTemplateLiterals: true
        }],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ]
    }
};
```

and I add this option as you see:

```
"ecmaFeatures": {
    "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
    "forOf": true,
},
```

but still has a problem with error: `[eslint] Parsing error: Unexpected token ...`

how can I solve this problem? other eslint notices works truly... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your parser/ecmaVersion to `2018`. Object spreads are new in ECMAScript 2018.

Comment: yes I know but when I switched to 2018 my nodejs global.variable has error from eslint

Comment: I find my problem for global vars and thank you for your help :)